# javascript form validation with multiple field and display on site

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, validation

So, hey, I know that there's more than someone could want of this type of question, but maybe I can present it with a little twist, i have try to mix different thing reader here and there, but when i submit the form the validation process don't run and it just submit directly the form. It's a one go script, and it go like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var errors =[];

    function printarray(array){
            for (var i=0; i<array.lenght; i++){
                document.write(array[i]);
            }
    }

    function validate(){

        document.getElementById("npostform").elements["contenidotext"].value=window.frames["contenido"].document.body.innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("npostform").elements["resumentext"].value=window.frames["resumen"].document.body.innerHTML;

        if (document.npostform.titulo.value=="" || document.npostform.titulo.value==null){
            errors.push("Se debe especificar un titulo <br>");
        } 
        if (document.npostform.contenidotext.value=="" || document.npostform.contenidotext.value==null){
            errors.push("Se debe incluir un contenido <br>");
        }
        if (document.npostform.resumentext.value=="" || document.npostform.resumentext.value==null){
            errors.push("Se debe incluir un resumen <br>");
        }

        if(errors.length >0){
            for (var i=0; i<errors.lenght; i++){
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML=printarray(errors);
            }
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }

    }


</script>

<div id="error"></div>

<form action="entradas.php" name="npostform" id="npostform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate();">

    <label for="Titulo">Titulo:</label>
    <input type="text" name="titulo" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['titulo'])) { echo $_SESSION['titulo'];} ?>">
                    <br>
    <label for="Categoria">Categoria-Seccion:</label>
    <select name="categoria" value= "<?php if(isset($_SESSION['categoria'])){echo $_SESSION['categoria'];} ?>">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
            foreach (tomarcategorias() as $order =>$categorias){
                $name = $categorias['name'];
                $id = $categorias['id'];
                $order =$categorias['order'];

                if ($categorias['type'] == 'Articulos'){
                    echo "<optgroup label='", $name, "'>";
                    foreach(tomarsecciones('idcategoria', $id) as $ord => $secciones){
                    $ord = $secciones['order'];
                    echo "<option value='", $secciones['id'], "'><PRE>", $secciones['name'], "</option>";
                }
            }
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <br>
    <textarea name="contenidotext" rows="15" cols="50" style="display:none;"></textarea>
    <iframe name="contenido" id="contenido" style="width:300; height:100; background: white;"></iframe>
    <br>
    <label>Resumen del articulo</label>
    <br>
    <textarea name="resumentext" rows="5" cols="50" style="display:none;"></textarea>
    <iframe name="resumen" id="resumen" style="background: white;"><?php if (isset($_SESSION['resumen'])) { echo $_SESSION['resumen'];}?></iframe>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="add_post" value="Subir post"/>

    </form>
```

I have to be sincere, in the head there is a linked javascript but that contain functions for buttons for a simple wysiwyg and already try to make all the script together, in the same and different files, didn't change a thing.

Does anybody know where the bug is? and also,is there a way to view the errors of javascript script as in php?

Comment: Could you replace the submit line with     `<input type="submit" onsubmit="return validate();" name="add_post" value="Subir post"/>`

Comment: This is caused because of js generating error on checking iframe data. So your submit is not running!

You can't check iframe's data like that. It is not an input tag so there is no value property on it. 

What do you want to do with iframe?

if you are trying to get input data from iframe then your form and your site must be using same domain or at least allow x-domain from web server.

Comment: sorry, yeah, have edited that, forgot to add that, the idea is to set the value of the texture equal to the one on the frames, like this: document.getElementById("npostform").elements["contenidotext"].value=window.frames["contenido"].document.body.innerHTML;
 
 document.getElementById("npostform").elements["resumentext"].value=window.frames["resumen"].document.body.innerHTML;

Comment: added, uploaded but nothing changed, i have edited the post so you can see how the code changed, thanks a lot